# Tab events in firefox(windows)

Tags: c++, firefox, winapi, browser, mozilla

What would be a reliable way to detect tab events(tab close/tab switch etc.) in firefox on windows? 
It was easy to do it for chrome with SetWinEventHook with subscriptions to the events EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW and EVENT_OBJECT_HIDE since each chrome tab has a separate content window but since firefox has just one top level window for all tabs in a browser window I couldn't figure out a way to catch tab events in firefox.

PS: Its my observation using spy++ that its just one top level window across tabs in firefox. I may be wrong here.

Comment: FireFox doesn't use standard Win32 controls for its UI, it is just one big custom-drawn window. You won't be able to get any events from it using the Win32 API.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that @RemyLebeau.